# Reading All the Even Offsets in a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams, kafka-python

I have this really strange ask and is unconventional in terms of Kafka usage. I would like to read all the even offsets in a Kafka topic. How do I do that using Kafka-Python package?

Comment: have you tried anything so far ?

Comment: just read all the offsets. if they're odd, you still read it but you don't use it afterwards.